# For what integer values of $m$ and $n$ is $\frac{4m-n}{n}$ a rational square?

Tags: geometry, elementary-number-theory, radicals

**Question** for what integer values of $m$ and $n$ with $(m,n)=1$ is $\frac{4m-n}{n}$ a rational square?

**Note** the motivation for this question is a curiosity i noticed, that the smallest angle of the 3-4-5 triangle is equal to the smallest angle of a triangle whose sides are $\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: By "rational square" do you mean a fraction like $a^2/b^2$ on it's simplest form?

Comment: yes, in my example $m=5$ and $n=2$ and we have $\frac{4 \times 5 -2}{2} = 3^2$

Comment: That's just a square number, so you want $4m-n = k^2n$ for some integer $k$?

Comment: @DavidHolden Does the result have to be an integral square (e.g. $3^2, 16^2, \ldots$) or can the result be other rational squares (e.g. $1/4=(1/2)^2, 9/16=(3/4)^2$)?

Comment: no, happy with any rational. the form i used was (perhaps unwisely) dictated by stylistic considerations. but as it works out in the geometrical context you actually have: $\tan \frac12\alpha = \sqrt{\frac{n}{4m-n}}$ so the result would be $\frac13$

Comment: One thing to note is that for $n=4$, any value for $m$ of the form $m=(2k)^2+1$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ works.

Comment: And for $n=2$, then any value of $m$ of the form $m=2k^2 + 2k + 1$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for rational points in the parabola $$x^2-4y+1=0.$$ It is easy to find one of such points, say $(0, 1/4)$. Take a line of rational slope $q$ that passes through $(0,1/4)$ and compute the intersection between the line and the parabola.

The line is $y=qx+\frac14$. Put this is the parabola equation to get $x^2-4qx=0$. Since you don't want the point where $x=0$ (a line and a parabola generally intersect at two points) the other point must have $x=4q$. This also shows the $y$ of the new point is $4q^2+\frac14$.

That is, take any rational $q$. Then $(x,y)=\left(4q, 4q^2+\frac 14\right)$ is a solution of our desired equation. Note that in the original problem, $m/n$ is our $y$. A more careful analysis shows these are actually all the solutions.

Comment: very nice answer, Ian - thank you. have you any idea of the direction of the more careful analysis required to show that your set exhausts the solutions?

Comment: Could you explain how you got from the question to finding rational points on that parabola, please?

Comment: Yes, we must show there is a bijection between the rational slope $q$ and a general rational point $R$ in the parabola. Bear with me: connect the two rational points $(0,1/4)$ and $R$ by a line. This line must have a rational slope (why?). So, for every $R$, there is a $q$. And, as you can see in the answer, every $q$ produces a unique rational point $R$. This shows there is a one-to-one correspondence between rational points and rational slopes.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz, $$x^2=\frac{4m-n}{n}=4\frac mn -1=4y-1,$$ so we want rationals $x$ and $y$ such that $x^2-4y+1=0$. Geometrically, this is a parabola.

Comment: @BeaumontTaz: Note that, if you've seen the expression for a generic Pythagorean triple, then you've seen the fruits of this tactic there as well. All conics can be parametrized this way, and so finding rational solutions of conics is straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

It should be written in the General form.

$$\frac{4x-y}{y}=z^2$$

$$y=2k$$

$$x=(2t^2+2t+1)k$$

$$z=2t+1$$

$y$ - can only be an even number.

Because the equation  $x^2-4y+1=0$  has no solutions in integers.